# how to get to play diff sound files for each event

Tags: javascript, css, html, audio

I am new to javaScript and need to make my flash cards play the corresponding sound when flipped i flip them with simple css but i cant get the javaScript to work correctly
here is my code

```
    body{
    background-image: url(../jpg/iconic-jacquard-towel-mountain-majesty-bath-towel-832373.jpg);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
    background-attachment: fixed;
    align-content: justify;
}
.flip3d{
width: 240px;
height: 200px;
margin: 10px;
float: left;
-webkit-box-shadow: inset 0px 0px;
box-shadow: inset 0px 0px;
}
.flip3d>.front{
position: absolute;
-webkit-transform: perspective( 800px ) rotateY( 0deg );
transform: perspective( 800px ) rotateY( 0deg );
background: #24C7BF;
width: 240px;
height: 200px;
border-radius: 7px;
-webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
backface-visibility: hidden;
transition: -webkit-transform .5s linear 0s;
transition: transform .5s linear 0s;
box-shadow: 10px 10px 11px #F7F2F2;
-webkit-box-shadow: 10px 10px 11px #F7F2F2;
}
    .flip3d>.back{
position: absolute;
-webkit-transform: perspective(800px) rotateY( 180deg);
transform: perspective(800px) rotateY( 180deg);
background: #8376F0;
width: 240px;
height: 200px;
border-radius: 7px;
-webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
backface-visibility: hidden;
transition: -webkit-transform .5s linear 0s;
transition: transform .5s linear 0s;
text-align: center;
font-size: 24px;
box-shadow: -10px 10px 11px #8A8A8A;
-webkit-box-shadow: -10px 10px 11px #8A8A8A;
}
.flip3d:hover > .front{
    -webkit-transform: perspective( 800px ) rotateY( -180deg);
    transform: perspective( 600px ) rotateY( -180deg);
}
    .flip3d:hover > .back{
    -webkit-transform: perspective( 800px ) rotateY( 0deg); 
    transform: perspective( 600px ) rotateY( 0deg);
}
p{
    padding:60px;
}
```

this is my script

```
   function play(audio1){
var audio = document.getElementById("audio1");
audio.play();
         }
   function play(audio2){
var audio = document.getElementById("audio2");
 audio.play();}
```

this is my html for the cards

```
<div class="flip3d">
<div value="play" onMouseOver="play(audio1);" onMouseOut="stop();" class="back"><p>Mshiimin maaba</p>
<audio id="audio1" src="../../soundbites/Giigoon.mp3"></audio>
</div>
<div class="front"><img src="pics/Apple-Fruit-PNG-File.png" width="200px" height="200px" alt="red apple"/></div>
</div>
<div class="flip3d">
<div value="play" onMouseOver="play(audio2);" onMouseOut="stop();" class="back"><p>Emtigoonhsibigak maaba</p>
<audio id="audio2" src="../../soundbites/Jidmoonh.mp3"></audio>
</div>
<div class="front"><img src="pics/Broccoli-PNG-File.png" width="210px" height="200px" alt="broccoli"/></div>
</div>
```

so what i want it to do is to flip card and say the word with the sound file that i have each card will have a different sound file and would want them to only make the sound when flipped to back side

Comment: right now as it stands it will only play the first of the sound files on all the cards

Comment: JaVaScRiPt Is NoT JaVa.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In js you have two same functions with passing different parametres, second function would not work as it has the same name, you can use same function for both and pass it just id name of the audio element as following:

```
function play($audio) {
  var audio = document.getElementByID($audio);
  audio.play()
}
```

In the html to onMouseOver event pass the function above with id name of the audio e.g. `onMouseOver="play('audio2');"`

This is full code:

```
<div class="flip3d">
<div value="play" onMouseOver="play('audio1');" onMouseOut="stop();" class="back"><p>Mshiimin maaba</p>
<audio id="audio1" src="../../soundbites/Giigoon.mp3"></audio>
</div>
<div class="front"><img src="pics/Apple-Fruit-PNG-File.png" width="200px" height="200px" alt="red apple"/></div>
</div>
<div class="flip3d">
<div value="play" onMouseOver="play('audio2');" onMouseOut="stop();" class="back"><p>Emtigoonhsibigak maaba</p>
<audio id="audio2" src="../../soundbites/Jidmoonh.mp3"></audio>
</div>
<div class="front"><img src="pics/Broccoli-PNG-File.png" width="210px" height="200px" alt="broccoli"/></div>
</div>
```

Let me know if it makes sense and if it works.